# api is accessing through ip but not with the domain in nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, apache2

i hosted a nodejs api on ec2 instance. it is accessing on instance IP over 4000  port.  but when I try to access it through the domain then it wasn't accessed.  I open the 4000 port on the security group of ec2 instance. for example http:12.11.11.10:4000(accessible) "http://example.com:4000"